# Open Id Connect Redirect Issue .Net Core 2.2

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, asp.net-core-2.0, openid-connect

I am setting up a connection with Quickbooks online and I am having an issue with OAuth.

I am using this project as a reference https://github.com/ehalsey-quickbooks and using the same code in my Startup.cs as the project is.

But in my controller action when I call the `Challenge` my `RedirectUri` is not working as expected.

For them to log in I call this on my controller action

```
return Challenge(new AuthenticationProperties() { RedirectUri = "http://localhost:61000/Dashboard/Index" }, "QuickBooks");
```

The request is authorizing fine with the identity server but instead of the redirect I am setting it is always changing it to.

`http://localhost:61000/signin-oidc`

I assume it does not have to redirect to the signin-oidc page after it successfully authenticates. If so how can I redirect it to a page of my choosing so I can pull out the tokens and do what I need to?

Comment: Share us detail steps to reproduce your issue, I made a test with [Step By Step Guide](https://github.com/ehalsey-quickbooks/QuickBooksASPNetCore2OpenIDConnect/wiki/Step-By-Step-Guide#add-the-redirect-uri), and your code, it redirect correctly after sign.

Comment: It looks like in this example they are using the /signin-oidc as their redirect point. I know that this is the default for Open Id Connect, but normally you can override that. I think that Quickbooks doesn't play nice with the `Challenge` command. The Challenge example I gave redirects to /signin-oidc but when I use their API Client `OAuth2Client oauthClient = new OAuth2Client("id", "secert", "http://localhost:61000/Test/LoginTest", "sandbox");` it redirects properly. I don't want to use their Nuget package because it conflicts another package I have but if I have to use it I will.

Comment: `Redirect` is controlled by `AddOpenIdConnect`, and it works correctly with me by `return Challenge(new AuthenticationProperties() { RedirectUri = "http://localhost:61000/Dashboard/Index" }, "QuickBooks");`. `/signin-oidc` is an endpoint which is handled by `AddOpenIdConnect` to accept access token from identity server. If you provide the `RedirectUri`, it will redirect to the provided value, if not, it will redirect to `/`. Share us a complete demo which could reproduce your issue.